send text message to un-subscribed user using AWS SNS service
In my application, I need to send a welcome text message with one customized URL to new users, using aws sns service without subscribing to the user and node.js how can I achieve this?

You can't use SNS to send mail/sms to unknown/unverified users, it is not intended for that purpose.
You can use the SES to do that, but by default it comes with sandbox, where you can't send mails to unverified users.
You have to get the production access to send mail to unknown/unverified users in SES.
Please check the below link for more info,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/request-production-access.html
[edited]
If you want to send text message to unverified users then you have send a request to AWS to enable the production env for SNS, by default it is in Sandbox. There you can send messages without any prior verification.
Please check the below link for more info,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-sms-sandbox-moving-to-production.html

are you talking about the text message or mail service, SES service is working for me, and I'm able to send mail to unverified users, my question is for text message service by AWS
